# Quartz Scheduler error in Eclipse - creating a new trigger

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying out Quartz Scheduler and I am writing a small test program in Eclipse, but the Eclipse editor keeps underlining in red the .withSchedule line.  The .build(); line also has a small red underline between the second parentheses and the semi-colon.

When I hover the mouse over .withSchedule, Eclipse says:

"The method withSchedule(CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder) is undefined for the type Date"

Here is the code:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.JobKey.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerKey.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class JobScheduler 
{

    Scheduler sched;


    public JobScheduler()
    {
        try 
        {
            SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
            sched.start();
        } 
        catch (SchedulerException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void scheduleEmailJob(String from, String to, String subject, String message)
    {

        JobDetail job = newJob(EmailJob.class)
                  .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")  
                  .usingJobData("from", from)
                  .usingJobData("to", to)
                  .usingJobData("subject", subject)
                  .usingJobData("message", message)
                  .build();

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
                .startAt(tomorrowAt(15, 0, 0)  
                .withSchedule(calendarIntervalSchedule()  // <------
                        .withIntervalInDays(1)) 
                .build();                                 // <------

        try 
        {
            sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } 
        catch (SchedulerException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I got the code snippet at the bottom of the page here:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/DailyTrigger

Comment: You've got an unclosed parentheses after tomorrowAt(15, 0, 0) for startAt method, so eclipse compiler tries to apply withSchedule method to a Date class instead of TriggerBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

try to create separate job class and configure your triggers, cron expression and scheduler factory in main class. this will help you out.

Comment: Is this something to try or will it help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1").startNow().build();
```

Use this.

Comment: Please consider improving your code-only answer by adding some explanation how this solves the problem.